# Show that if $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$, the set of all vectors of the form $x=\sum c_ne_n$ is a subspace of $H$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences, orthonormal

Show that if $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$, the set of all vectors of the form $x=\sum c_ne_n$ is a subspace of $H$.

Hint: Take a Cauchy sequences $(x_r)$, where $x_r=\sum c_{rn}e_n$. Set $C_r=(c_{r1},c_{r2},...)$ and show that $(C_r)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $l_2$. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The hint is irrelevant to the question as stated.  Do you mean to show that this set is a **closed** subspace of $H$?

Comment: I mean a subspace of a Hilbert space which is a Hilbert space too (not a vector subspace). Since Hilbert spaces are complete we know that every Cauchy sequence in the space converges to a point in the space. I think this is where the hint becomes useful.

Comment: Okay,  now that makes sense.  So: you've given us the problem statement, but where in particular are you having trouble?  Is it the bookkeeping involved with sequences of sequences?

Comment: Can you see why the mapping $\sum c_n e_n \mapsto (c_1,c_2,\dots)$ is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah pretty much, I'm not sure how to start and I don't really understand the hint.

Comment: I see why that mapping is true, but I don't see how it is an isomorphism of a Hilbert space.

Comment: Do you see that $\|\phi(x)\| = \|x\|$? (Here, $\phi$ denotes the map $\phi: \sum c_n e_n \mapsto (c_1,c_2,\dots)$).  Do you see that $\phi$ is onto?

Comment: Your coefficients $c_n$ in $x=\sum c_ne_n$ must be subjects to a restriction of convergence (Its cannot be arbitrary)

Comment: In order that $\sum_n c_n e_n$ makes sense, you need $c \in l_2$. There is something missing in the question as posed.

Comment: @1233dfv Since you are the user who created (subspaces) tag, I wanted to let you know about this discussion on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21345/what-to-do-with-the-subspaces-tag

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess we can assume that our orthonormal set is infinite. If it's finite then it's pretty easy. Let's start with 
$$
|C_n-C_m| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_{n,i}-c_{m,i}|^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_{n,i}e_i-c_{m,i}e_i|^2\right)^{1/2}=|x_n-x_m|
$$
where the last equality follows from rearranging an absolutely convergent sequence.

We assumed $x_i$ is a Cauchy sequence, so $C_i$ is a cauchy sequence as well. But completeness of $\ell_2$ tells us $C_i \to Y$ for $Y=(y_1,y_2,...)$. Then we want to see that

$$
x_i \to \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_ie_i :=y
$$

This is clear as 
$$
|C_n-Y| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_{n,i}-y_i|^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_{n,i}e_i-y_ie_i|^2\right)^{1/2}=|x_i-y|
$$
again with a rearrangement. So we're done

You can see how the isomorphism @Omnomnomnom mentioned works in this proof. We use the isomorphism move into $\ell^2$ to use its completeness. Then we pullback to see that it worked in the original space.